# C# webserver and ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in Chrome

Tags: c#, http, google-chrome

I have been using [this C# webserver](http://webserver.codeplex.com/) embedded in a Windows service for a few years now and, whilst it has it's moments, it's been pretty stable the whole time.

Recently users have been reporting Chrome giving them a `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error message whenever they access the internally hosted web console.  You can access the same console with no problems in IE.

The reports are recent, so I rolled back to older versions of my code and still the same issue, again only in Chrome.

I ran a curl against the URL to see if there was anything nasty in there, this is an example request that will fail in Chrome after a few refreshes:
`curl -vl -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt http://localhost:56552/admin`

```
    * Adding handle: conn: 0x1ff51e0
    * Adding handle: send: 0
    * Adding handle: recv: 0
    * Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
    * - Conn 0 (0x1ff51e0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
    * About to connect() to localhost port 56552 (#0)
    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 56552 (#0)
    > GET /admin HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
    > Host: localhost:56552
    > Accept: */*
    > Cookie: __session_id=81baa233e1f742b3a510c7746775f49c
    >
    < HTTP/1.1 200 Completed - YAMS
    < Content-Type: text/html
    < Content-Length: 5409
    < Connection: Close
    < Date: Tue, 03 Sep 2013 14:11:19 GMT
    * Server C# WebServer is not blacklisted
    < Server: C# WebServer
    <
    <lots of html>
    </html>
    * Closing connection 0
```

**QUESTION**:  Is this a problem in a recent update to Chrome?  Every search for the error message produces lots of questions, but very few answers.

Is it a problem in the way the HTTP response is handled that only Chrome is being strict about?

Any ideas how to diagnose further and ideally fix?

I was in the process of ripping the webserver component out anyway and rewriting it myself, but I need this resolved soon, there's ~5k servers affected.